# Magento2 - How to get Product Id in FinalPriceBox Plugin

Tags: magento2, finalpricebox

How to get Product Id in FinalPriceBox Plugin in magento 2

Using FinalPriceBox Plugin to hide price in all page how to get a product id within this plugin.

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
     <plugin name="vendor_module_finalpricebox" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\FinalPriceBox"/>
</type>
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/FinalPriceBox.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Vendor\Module\Block\Button;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\HidePrice;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox as FinalPriceBoxRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

use function strstr;

/**
 * Class FinalPriceBox
 */
class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    /** @var ScopeConfigInterface */
    private $config;
    private $buttonBlock;
    private $hidePriceHelper;
     protected $productRepository;
    /**
     * FinalPriceBox constructor.
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param Button $buttonBlock
     * @param Data $hidePriceHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        HidePrice $hidePriceHelper,
        Button $buttonBlock
    )
    {
        $this->config          = $config;
        $this->buttonBlock     = $buttonBlock;
        $this->hidePriceHelper = $hidePriceHelper;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;


    }

    /**
     * @param FinalPriceBoxRenderer $finalPriceBox
     * @param $result
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundToHtml(FinalPriceBoxRenderer $finalPriceBox, $result)
    {

        //How to get Product id in this plugin
        $template = 'button.phtml';
        return $this->buttonBlock
                    ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::' . $template)
                    ->toHtml();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: no, i didn`t  found any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this below plugin code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

/**
 * Class FinalPriceBox
 */
class FinalPriceBox {

    public function aroundToHtml($subject, callable $proceed) {
        if ($subject->getSaleableItem()->getId() == 1) {
            return ''; // Remove final price box
        } else {
            return $proceed(); // Display final price box
        }

    }
}
```

You can get product id by this code : **$subject->getSaleableItem()->getId()**

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: i was already tried a above method its reflects https://prnt.sc/r1ogjg

Comment: Can you please upload your plugin full code after use my answer?

Comment: its workings  i  fix the issue in di.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * @param FinalPriceBoxRenderer $finalPriceBox
     * @param $result
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundToHtml(FinalPriceBoxRenderer $finalPriceBox, $result)
    {
        // it gets you the product id
        $productId = $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();

       // $this->getSaleableItem() holds the instance of the current product

        $template = 'button.phtml';
        return $this->buttonBlock
                    ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::' . $template)
                    ->toHtml();
    }
```

Comment: I was already used this  term `$this->getSaleableItem()->getId();`  but its gives on error as a  call to undefinite   getId()